# Google Cloud - Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to get the OS Image Name of a Google Cloud Instance Using REST API provided by Google. Tried lot of API's in Google API Explorer and have no idea how to get the OS Type. My Case is to populate "Windows" if the OS Type of Instance is Windows and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The OS information is listed under "Source image" on the details of your boot disk.

Using the [instance-get method of the API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get) and searching for the "disk" parameters you can retrieve this information.

Comment: "guestOsFeatures": [
    {
     "type": "WINDOWS"
    },
    {
     "type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
    },
    {
     "type": "MULTI_IP_SUBNET"
    }
   ]
This is for Windows Instance.
"guestOsFeatures": [
    {
     "type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
    }
   ]
But, i am not able to get "Linux", If the Instance is Linux type

Comment: Which type are you using? Ubuntu? CentOS? Did you tried with another versions?  Are you using an account with the right permissions/roles?

Comment: I am using Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch). Yeah I do have Admin Access to all the API's

Comment: What about "sourceImage"? Do you have anything? If you are using a custom image make sure to enable the features [1].

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#guest-os-features

Comment: I am not using any Custom Images

Comment: Seems to be working for me, confirm that you are using the GET option over the right project.

Comment: "sourceImage": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-2008-r2-dc-v20190108", I am Getting the Whole Link

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I don't think directly retrieving the OS image name of a Google Cloud Instance using a single REST API call is possible. However, you could initially use the [instances.get](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get) method from the Google Compute Engine API to retrieve information about a specific instance. This will provide details like the boot disk attached to the instance.

Next analyse the boot disk information,it will be in the format

```
projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/{os-family}
```

This way, you can identify the OS type based on the os-family element (e.g., "debian-9").